# Is photon drive reaction less propulsion?

Tags: photons, propulsion, solar-sails

If photon dont have mass how can produce thrust, it seems that violate Newton 3. law?

If light dont have mass how can push solar sail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not violate Newton's third law, since although photons have no mass, they still have momentum given by $$p=\frac Ec$$ where $E$ is energy and $c$ the speed of light.

Comment: So massless or reaction less propulsion exist?

Comment: It's massless but there is a reaction. If photons move in one direction, there must be momentum change in the other direction.

Comment: Has photon drive enough thrust for move car,aircraft, boats on earth?

Comment: If you have photons of arbitrary energy and flux, and a large enough sail, I guess so.